# Coloring a $10×10$ grid

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring, invariance

Given a $10×10$ grid with $9$ red blocks and $91$ white blocks, in each step we color one red block black and after that one white block red until there are $91$ black blocks and $9$ red blocks. Prove that there exits a step in which a black block shares an edge with a white block.

I ran a few trials and couldn't get past the fifth step without adjacency. But I don't know how to build a proof.

Comment: I suspect you can get some mileage out of thinking of a red/black domain and a white domain (either of them possibly disconnected).  To avoid the situation described, the entire border of the red/black domain must be red.  What stops the red/black domain from expanding to cover the entire board without violating that condition?  (Keep in mind that you don't have to worry about the edge of the board being red—just the border with the white domain.)

Comment: Still can't quite understand how to prove the existence of the step. Could you please explain more?@Brian Tung

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by contradiction there is no step in which a black block shares an edge with a white block.

Consider the first time a row or column gets completely colored black. Assume WLOG its the $n$th row. Of course there is a column without any red block, since there are only $9$ of these. This column must be completely black, otherwise there would some black block sharing an edge with a white block in the column. So both the row and the column were colored black in this step, i.e., in the previous step their intersection were red.

[image]

Now again, there is a row in this step without any red block and its not the $n$th this time. Furthermore, there is no row without a black block and no row with only black blocks, so there must be some black block sharing an edge with a white block. Contradiction!